# Unix script can't alter postgres hba.conf configuration file on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, postgresql, ubuntu, unix, vagrant

I'm attempting to setup postgres 9.6 on ubuntu/vagrant through a provisioning script. Part of my script adds a line to `pg_hba.conf` with the following command:

`sudo -u postgres echo "host    all             all             all                     md5" >> /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf`

However, this gives me the error `-bash: /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf: Permission denied`

Which is strange because I am allowed to edit the file with either `sudo nano` or `sudo -u postgres nano`.

Here are the permissions on the file:
`-rw-r----- 1 postgres postgres  4641 Apr  6 16:11 pg_hba.conf`

How can I add this line to my configuration file in a script?

Comment: Your `sudo` is covering the `echo`, but not the `>>`. If you quote the whole thing, it should work better.

Comment: Does `echo "host..." | sudo tee -a filename` work?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' that seems to work. Would you add an answer so that I can credit you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that redirection happens *before* command execution. So the redirection doesn't have the elevated privileges you expected it to.

There's more than one way around that problem. I generally use something like this.

```
echo "host..." | sudo tee -a /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf
```

Piping to `sudo tee...` avoids problems with quoting.

---

[How bash executes commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html#Simple-Command-Expansion)

[Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirections)